# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when parsing JSON string with HTML inside

Tags: php, javascript, json

This problem has been clogging up my error log for quite a while now. The function is doing what I want it to do, but this message is driving me crazy!

```
function togglePreview( link_id ) {  
        var data = { ajax_cmd: 'get_embed_html', link_id: link_id };
        jQuery.post("?", data, function(json) {
            if (json.html) {
                jQuery( "#listen_" + link_id ).html( json.html );
            }
        }, "json"); 
}
```

Server side, I have a couple of lines of PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$html = get_embed_html( $_REQUEST['link_id'] );
echo json_encode( array("html" => $html) ); 
?>
```

The JSON string from the server outputs as follows:

```
{"html":"<iframe frameborder=0 height=400 width=100% src='http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=ozhtg6FuD8A'><\/iframe><noscript>JavaScript is required to load the comments.<\/noscript>\n<div class=\"inline-comments-container\" name=\"comments\">\n    <div id=\"inline_comments_ajax_handle\" class=\"last-child\" data-post_id=\"26\">\n    <div id=\"inline_comments_ajax_target\" style=\"display: none;\"><\/div>\n    <div class=\"inline-comments-loading-icon\">Loading Comments&#8230;<\/div>\n    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"inline_comments_nonce\" value=\"c16a7993ab\" id=\"inline_comments_nonce\" \/>\n            <div class=\"inline-comments-content\">\n            <div class=\"inline-comments-p\">\n                <form action=\"javascript:\/\/\" method=\"POST\" id=\"default_add_comment_form\">\n                    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"inline_comments_nonce\" value=\"c16a7993ab\" id=\"inline_comments_nonce\" \/>\n                    <span class=\"inline-comments-profile-pic-container\"><img alt='' src='https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/FACEBOOKID\/picture?type=large' class='avatar avatar-32 photo' height='32' width='32' \/><\/span>                    <textarea placeholder=\"Press enter to submit comment&#8230;\" tabindex=\"4\" id=\"comment\" name=\"comment\" id=\"inline-comments-textarea\" class=\"inline-comments-auto-expand submit-on-enter\"><\/textarea>\n                    <!--<span class=\"inline-comments-more-handle\"><a href=\"#\">more<\/a><\/span>-->\n                    <div class=\"inline-comments-more-container\" style=\"display: none;\">\n                        <div class=\"inline-comments-field\"><input type=\"text\" tabindex=\"5\" name=\"user_name\" id=\"inline_comments_user_name\" placeholder=\"Name&#8230\" value=\"greeny\"  \/><\/div>\n                        <div class=\"inline-comments-field\"><input type=\"email\" required tabindex=\"5\" name=\"user_email\" id=\"inline_comments_user_email\" placeholder=\"Email&#8230\" value=\"email@example.com\"  \/><\/div>\n                        <div class=\"inline-comments-field\"><input type=\"url\" required tabindex=\"6\" name=\"user_url\" id=\"inline_comments_user_url\" placeholder=\"Website&#8230\" value=\"\" \/><\/div>\n                    <\/div>\n                <\/form>\n            <\/div>\n        <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n<\/div>"}
```

When calling the JS function togglePreview(4), i receive the following error code:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Hopefully it's something very simple I've overlooked!

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you passing html wrapped in json? This seems unnecessary. Just pass the html then you can avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: According to http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ your JSON seems valid. This error is from JS but from the code you posted, does not seem anything is wrong. Maybe other part of your code?

Comment: Provided piece of code looks good to me. HTML does not contain scripts, so that should not be an issue. Just go through your code an carefully check that you have correct pairs of opening and closing brackets

Comment: Where does the error message come from? PHP or JavaScript? Which line, which file?

Comment: Deadron - I'm going to be returning extra parameters, so eventually it will need to be wrapped in JSON

Comment: Are you sure that the error is not caused by something in some other part of the application? Can you state what line the error is actually occuring in? Chrome, for instance, should tell you when you run your script.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have magic_quotes_runtime on? That could add random escape chars to your json string.